# JS method bound this refers to previous version

Tags: javascript, bind, es6-class

I know that probably there might be a better way to do this, but I want to understand how to solve this kind of problem. I have two classes,  `Parent`and `Child`. `Parent` holds an array of children.

I created a `addChild` and `removeChild` methods that allow me to create a `Child` and remove it and both return me the updated `Parent` object ( I need it because it is going to update a React state variable somewhere else)

I want to pass to each child a method "remove" in order to remove it from its parent.
This actually works fine on a preset parent with children. But if I add many children and then try to remove one, everytime I go back to the initial condition, (say, `Parent` initially has 4 children, I add 3 more, now they're 7. I remove one and go back to 4.).

I think this happens because when I pass the handler to the `Child` object I'm creating in `addChild`, the `removeChild`function I embed in the child is not updated and refers to the initial version of the `Parent` object, but I don't know how to fix this.

I attach here some pseudocode, just to give an idea of the problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
import _ from "lodash";

class Parent{
    constructor(){
       this.removeChild.bind(this);
    }

    children: Child[];
    addChild(){
       const newParent = _.cloneDeep(this);
       newParent.children = [
       ...newParent.children, 
       new Child({remove: this.removeChild})
       ]
       return newParent;
    }

    removeChild(child){
        const newParent = _.cloneDeep(this);
        newParent.children = newParent.filter(child => (child.id != child.id));
        return newParent;  
    }
}

class Child{
    id;   
    remove();

   constructor({remove}){
       this.id = automaticgenerated
       this.remove = remove
   }
}
```

Comment: In your case, wouldn't it just be `newParent.removeChild`?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```js
class Parent {
    constructor() {
        this.children = [];
    }

    addChild(child) {
        child.parent = this;
        this.children.push(child);
        return this;
    }

    removeChild(child) {
        child.parent = null;
        this.children = this.children.filter(c => c.id != child.id);
        return this;
    }
}

class Child {
    constructor() {
        this.parent = null;
        this.id = Math.random(); //Fake auto generated id
    }

    remove() {
        this.parent.removeChild(this);
        this.parent = null;
    }
}

const p = new Parent();
const c1 = new Child();
const c2 = new Child();

console.log(p.addChild(c1));
console.log(p.addChild(c2));
console.log(p.removeChild(c2));

c1.remove();
console.log(p);
```

Comment: Yes! though I found out that most of my problems came from the fact that these objects were used within react components and were not correctly updated :)